# android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1 while im not explicitly setting index

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I am trying to print a value out of a database into a TextView, but it gives me this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flybyfinal/com.example.flybyfinal.accountActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
```

I use this method to get the record which I have in a DBH class:

```
public Cursor  displayUserInfo(String username) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + users + " WHERE username = ?", new String[]{username});

    return cursor;
}
```

and I call it here in the account activity:

```
TextView account = findViewById(R.id.txtUsernameAcc);
    DBH db = new DBH(accountActivity.this);
    Cursor cursor = db.displayUserInfo(loginActivity.accountName);
    account.setText(cursor.getString(0));
```

Comment: You are using sqlite, not mysql!

Comment: Hint: your cursor is pointing to row -1 when you try to read it. Have a look at e.g. Cursor#moveToFirst()

Comment: thank you very much it fixed my problem. how do I close a question or mark it as solved, or should i just delete the question
?